# ln -s fail to create a symbolic to directory

Tags: symbolic-link

I tried to create a symbolic link of Books Directory to the Home

```
#in the Document Directory to the Home Diretory.
ln -s Books/ ~/Books
```

[image]

but it create a file rather than a directory

What's the problem with my usage of ln?

Comment: `ln -s /home/username/Documents/Books /home/username/Books`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like 3rd form according to documentation:

> ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
>   ...
>   In the 3rd and 4th forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.

So it reads as "create link to a directory `Books` (which is in your current working directory) and put that link in specified directory `~/Books`". Of course, if `Books/` doesn't exist in current working directory - you'll have a symlink pointing to itself, which will result in too many symlink levels error

```
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 01:57:21 UTC 2019 ]$ ln -s asdfasdf foobarbaz/
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 01:57:33 UTC 2019 ]$ ls foobarbaz/
asdfasdf  file.txt  thing
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 01:57:37 UTC 2019 ]$ ls -l foobarbaz/
total 0                                                                                                                                  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 8 Feb 22 01:57 asdfasdf -> asdfasdf                                                                           
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adminx adminx 0 Feb 22 01:56 file.txt                                                                                       
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 5 Feb 22 01:56 thing -> thing       
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 02:02:29 UTC 2019 ]$ cd foobarbaz/thing
bash: cd: foobarbaz/thing: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Now, I would suggest using first form with `-T` flag:

```
 adminx:Fri Feb 22 02:05:01 UTC 2019 ]$ ln -s -T  ~/Documents  dock_link
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 02:05:08 UTC 2019 ]$ ls -l dock_link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 22 Feb 22 02:05 dock_link -> /home/adminx/Documents
[ adminx:Fri Feb 22 02:05:16 UTC 2019 ]$
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you created a broken link. `Books/` is in `~/Documents`, so you need to specify that, either with a relative path:

```
ln -s Documents/Books ~/Books
```

or an absolute path:

```
ln -s ~/Documents/Books ~/Books
```